# Autofilling table rows from one data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with some data (all unique) like:

```
id   Name    Surname    Age
 1    Jack    Gong      21 
 2   Danny   Manny      24
```

If I insert one more row and write only surname as `Gong` to the cell, then is there any Excel function that fills the "Age", "Name" and "id" automatically to `21`, `Jack` and `1`?

Comment: You can have an INDEX MATCH function that will lookup the value and show the associated data.

Comment: If you want the new row to be identical to one already existing, then copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *automatic* way (outside of a VBA procedure, perhaps) to do this, but you can set something up that will do it through formulas:

1. Using the below picture, place the formula shown in the formula bar into cell A4, then copy into cell B4 and D4.
2. Then to insert a new row, copy this row and paste in the next row and input the new surname in column C. The id, name and age columns will look if that value has been entered above and fill the results if so.
3. If the value is not listed, the id, name and age columns will return blanks, at which point you can enter them manually.
4. Each time you insert a new row, ensure that you have a row full of formulas for id, name and age. (Alternatively, you can copy these down from above rows individually as well - notice all the appropriate cell locking to ensure it always captures the entire range).

[image]

Comment: you can remove $ sign if you dont want to fix range.